# How do I reverse the effects of a rebase on my git branch?

Tags: git, rebase

I have three branches, one `main` and two branches I've been working off, `A` and `B`. I've kept `main` up to date with the origin and had pushed out `A`. Before pushing `B`, though, I made a mistake and rebased both `A` and `main` onto it. This means that the PR for `B` includes `A`.

So `B` now looks something like this: `main --> A' --> B'` (where A' is the extra commits in A not in main)

How do I reverse the effects and extract `A'` from `B`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always roll back to an earlier commit using the hash.  It's been answered in a bunch of places but this is as good as any: [How to revert Git repository to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/revert-to-a-previous-git-commit)

Comment: I'm not trying to just roll back. I want to end up with B looking like `main --> B'`, i.e. I want to excise `A'` from the B branch.

Comment: Right, so jump back to where it looks like what you want and then rebase again.

Comment: Oh, you're saying to do `git rebase -i` to choose what I want on this path.